# Best approach to use Many to Many in Django + SQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, model

I am making a web app and i wish to use many to many fields in models.I haven't given much thought before and have simply used many to many field in models but now i am thinking how actually these many to many are stored in database and what would be the best approach when using Many to Many Fields in Models.

Approach 1:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 190,blank = False,null = False)
    about = models.CharField(max_length = 260,blank = False,null = True)
    website = models.URLField(blank = False)
    address  = models.OneToOneField(Address,related_name="org_address",on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    admin = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name="org_admin",blank = False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
```

OR
Approach 2:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 190,blank = False,null = False)
    about = models.CharField(max_length = 260,blank = False,null = True)
    website = models.URLField(blank = False)
    address  = models.OneToOneField(Address,related_name="org_address",on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)

class CompanyAdmin(models.Model):
    admin = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name="org_admin",blank = False)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company,related_name="company",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Do both methods handle many to many fields in the same way ?

I am using MySQL as Database

Update
"To make them Equivalent, Second Approach should have field as **ForiegnKey** and not **many to many**"
also to avoid multiple company admin entries Field company should be one to one.

*Solution*

> Do not create join tables as Django ORM Handles this itself.

Comment: No, by using a `CompanyAdmin` you creates an extra table, so now the many-to-many relation uses two intermediate tables. It also results in the fact that you can add the same `User` in *multiple* `CompanyAdmin`s, and thus link it multiple times to the *same* `Company`.

Comment: to make the second example equivalent, `admin` in `CompanyAdmin` would have to be a `ForeignKey` (not a `ManyToManyField`) - but one of the advantages of Django's ORM is you don't have to create this intermediate "join table" yourself, so I don't see any benefit to doing it that way.

Comment: ok, assuming instead of foreignkey in 2nd Approach , one to one field is used.Wouldn't the approach 1 also create a different table automatically to handle many to many field ?

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thanks, that is what i was thinking.Now this clears it.

Comment: @Dushyant Deshwal: even if you make a `OneToOneField`, it would result in constructing an extra table, which will result in an extra `JOIN` when querying, and more disk usage. So it is not a good idea to add such extra model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but now I am thinking how actually these many to many are stored in database.

Django will construct a model that has two `ForeignKey`s, one to the `Company` and one to the `User` model. This model thus corresponds to the [*junction table* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) between the `Company` and `User` model.

A `ManyToManyField` thus does not map on a *column*. The `ManyToManyField` is more a concept that enables one to write simpler queries, and provides a more convenient interface.

> Do both methods handle many to many fields in the same way ?

**No**. With the latter you will make *two* extra tables, one for the `CompanyAdmin` model, and one for the `ManyToManyField` between `CompanyAdmin` and `User`. It would also result in more `JOIN`s to fetch the companies for which a `User` is an admin for example, and it would here be possible to construct *multiple* `CompanyAdmin`s for the same `Company`, and thus linking the same `User` multiple times.

You can define however custom attributes in the junction table, by specifying the junction model explicitly with the [**`through=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through):

```
from django.conf import settings

class Company(models.Model):
    admin = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='org_admin',
        through='CompanyAdmin'
    )
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class CompanyAdmin(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: Django's [**`DateTimeField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)
> has a [**`auto_now_add=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField.auto_now_add)
> to work with timestamps. This will automatically assign the current datetime
> when creating the object, and mark it as non-editable (`editable=False`), such
> that it does not appear in `ModelForm`s by default.